# Is there a land cover type image collection on Google Earth Engine that covers the period 2000-2020?

Tags: google-earth-engine, time-series, land-cover

I am conducting an analysis that requires a land cover type time series for the period 2000-2020. The only land cover type time series that I could find covering this period is the one being produced as part of the ESA's [Climate Change Initiative (CCI)](http://maps.elie.ucl.ac.be/CCI/viewer/index.php) project. However, the interface that this project provides to access the data doesn't have a spatial filtering mechanism and thus the file size are enormous (more than 40GBs in my case).

Since my internet doesn't allow such massive downloads, I want to use GEE instead. Now, the only collection that I can find there is the [MCD12Q1 v6 product](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/MODIS_006_MCD12Q1?hl=en) which unfortunately only covers the period 2001-2016. The other one is the [Copernicus Global Land Cover Layers](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/COPERNICUS_Landcover_100m_Proba-V-C3_Global?hl=en) (CGLS-LC100) which only covers the period 2015-2019.
My question is: doesn't GEE really have a land cover type product covering this period? I find it odd to say the least.

Comment: Even though it doesn't say so in the MCD12Q1 Data page, it should be available all the way up to 2019. So if you can deal with 2000 and 2020 missing it could still be a good option

Answer (score 0):

Try using the CCDC tools to create landcover maps as you use them.

It's more work but would allow more flexibility without having to create landcover model code from scratch, whilst allowing you to reference the authors rather than reporting on the validations of the method yourself.
https://github.com/parevalo/gee-ccdc-tools